# How does Google Search Console detect pages with bad Web Vitals?

Tags: lighthouse, google-search-console, pagespeed-insights

I can see in Google Search Console a group of 30 pages with *need improvement LCP (longer than 2.5s)*. I checked all 20 listed URLs in Page Speed Insights and there's no **Field Data** but **Lab Data LCP** was less than 1s for each page.

Why does Google Search Console report pages without Field Data? Is it possible that in a group of 30 pages, only one is broken and others inherit bad LCP because the Field data is missed (each page has Origin LCP 2.6s)?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Search Console (GSC) report is based on the field data which is sourced from CrUX. It tends to group pages when it does not have enough data.

Page Speed insights only reports on individual pages or the whole site (origin).

So GSC can fit a middle ground where it reports on groups of pages.

Comment: do you know, how to remove a false/redundant pages (without Field Data but with good performance) reported by GSC?  
Revalidation didn't solve the problem. All of them are reported again. Maybe I should open each page everyday, to trigger Field Data (CrUX)?

Comment: I don't think one person viewing a page can make a difference. There are thresholds a page or group of pages need to make before being included.